# How to allow minus sign for package name in .proto file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

Here is the `.proto` file I used:

**pkg/apis/workflow/v1alpha1/generated.proto**

```proto
syntax = 'proto2';

package go-server.com.argo-new.pkg.apis.workflow.v1alpha1;

import "k8s.io/api/core/v1/generated.proto";
import "k8s.io/api/policy/v1beta1/generated.proto";
import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/generated.proto";
import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/generated.proto";
import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema/generated.proto";

// Package-wide variables from generator "generated".
option go_package = "v1alpha1";

// ArchiveStrategy describes how to archive files/directory when saving artifacts
message ArchiveStrategy {
  optional TarStrategy tar = 1;

  optional NoneStrategy none = 2;
}
```

When I tried to compile:

```sh
protoc -I /usr/local/include -I . -I ./vendor -I /root/go/src \
       -I /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.1/gogoproto \
       -I /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.12.2/third_party/googleapis \
       --include_imports --gogofast_out=plugins=grpc:/root/go/src \
       --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true:/root/go/src \
       --swagger_out=logtostderr=true,fqn_for_swagger_name=true:. \ 
       pkg/apis/workflow/v1alpha1/generated.proto
```

it reminds me that:

```sh
pkg/apis/workflow/v1alpha1/generated.proto:6:11: Expected ";"
```

It's a compile error which means the package name should not contain `-`.

Are there any methods to use `-` in package name or any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Dashes are illegal in Go package names: https://play.golang.org/p/CWQknBi2suT

Comment: Thanks, but dashes are allowed in the import path of Go, like `go-server.com.argo-new.pkg.apis.workflow.v1alpha1`. But when we use this package in protobuf, the dashes are not allowed. 
What I really want is to use dash character in the import path in protobuf, so we can auto-generate golang codes via protobuf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Protobuf**

It's not allowed, neither by [proto2 specs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec) (as in your example code) nor by [proto3 specs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec).

As shown in the specs (either of above mentioned), a `package` declaration follows the pattern:

> `package = "package" fullIdent ";"`

i.e. the keyword `package` followed by a `fullIdent` followed by one `;` semicolon, where `fullIdent` is defined as:

> `fullIdent = ident { "." ident }`

i.e. at least one `ident` followed by zero or more other `ident`'s preceded by `.`, where `ident` is defined as:

> `ident = letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }`

i.e. at least one letter, followed by zero or more letters (`[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`), digits (`[0-9]`), or the underscore `_` character.

So in conclusion, you can't have a minus (dash) `-` character in your protobuf package name.

---

**Go**

Additionally, as @colm.anseo pointed out, [Go package names](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause) also don't allow dash `-` characters either:

`PackageName = identifier .` where `identifier = letter { letter | unicode_digit } .`

([The underscore character is considered a letter](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Letters_and_digits).)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Of course Go package name allows dash `-` character, as can be seen in this [permalink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/0d2299e227441205bda34cc84f472a7cae0ef7f1/pkg/controller/deployment/deployment_controller.go#L41)

Comment: @KonnaseLee no it doesn't, you're confusing the [package name](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause) with the [import declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations). What contains the dash is the full import path, not the package name. In that link, `clientset` is the package name and `"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"` is the **import path**. The import path can contain dashes.

Comment: sorry to mix up the package name and import path. What I really want is to use dash character in the import path in protobuf, so we can auto-generate golang codes via protobuf. 
Looks like there is no way for me to achieve the goal. 
Thanks anyway !